# need help finding error in code to filter form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

This is the code I am using in order to try and filter a forms subform according to the dates in the txt boxes. The code is having a compile error, stopping at the third # with a "expect expression" and I can't figure out why.  I got this code from another location and simply tried to use it for my purposes. I know nothing about vba.

```
Private Sub btnDateRange_Click()
Me.Filter = "[tblDeliveries].[DeliveryID] Between #" & Me.StartDate & # AND #" & Me.EndDate & "#"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdApplyFilterSort
End Sub
```

would someone please point out what the issue is?  Thank you.

Comment: Why are you referencing DeliveryID field instead of a date/time field? Missing a quote mark in front of the second #.

Comment: Which form is this code behind and which form has the date textboxes? I suspect main form for both in which case it will not filter subform.

Comment: was trying to filter by the ID and not the date, changed that to DeliveryDate, added the quote mark, errors went away. The Form setup is Mainform: tblCustomers, Datasheet Subform: qryDeliveries.       Button with the code and textboxes for date entries are both on the parent. subform filters now, but only shows 1st record, the one tied to customer which comes up on parentform

Comment: That's normally the way related form/subform works. Only related records display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct syntax:

```vb
Private Sub btnDateRange_Click()
Me.Filter = "[tblDeliveries].[DeliveryID] Between #" & Format(Me.StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format(Me.EndDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```